# error with my matlab code

Tags: matlab, image-processing

i have a problem with this code as it's not working!! and i have no idea why !
i was trying to creat a gaussain pyramid to get a multi-resolution image , but while i was attempting to run this code this problem appeard
(((Error:Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.)))
 , i've tried to solve it several times but i failed ! .. this code is very necessary for me as i need it for my graduation project .

```
clear

clc
% create the convolution kernel 

%    kernel size
size = 8 ;             

%     standard deviation  used  for antialiasing
std_dev= 0.8 ; 

%     convolution kernel used to smooth the image before sampling
k = zeros(size);

%  Gaussian mean value
m = size / 2 ;

%     set the initial value of  k_accomulate
k_accom = 0;

%  getting the value for the normalized kernel

for i=1:1:size
    for j=1:1:size

        k(i,j) = exp(-((i-m).^2+(j-m).^2)/(2*std_dev.^2))/(2*pi*std_dev.^2);                          
        k_accom = k_accom + k(i,j);                                                                                           

    end;
end;

% to get the normalized value

for i=1:1:size
    for j=1:1:size

        k(i,j) = k(i,j)/k_accom ;                                                                                                    %      normalized kernel value for each  i and j 

    end;
end;

% kernel values are ready 

% Before sampling the image is convolved with a gaussian filter

% read the Original Image

image1= imread('1.jpg');

old_size= size(image1);

% set the reduction factor

red_factor= 2 ;

% convolve filter kernel with the picture
                                                                                                                                                                                               % conv_img = image;     X  forget it
%  conv_img = filter2(k,image);

% compute the size of the reduced image

    new_row = old_size(1)/red_factor;
    new_col = old_size(2)/red_factor;

% extract the reduced image 

    new_image = zeros(new_row,new_col);
    for i=1:1:new_row
        for j=1:1:new_col
            new_image(i,j) = conv_img(i*red_factor,j*red_factor);
        end;
    end;

imshow(new_image);
```

Comment: Which line has the error? Have you tried debugging? You are probably passing a `0` as an index to a matrix...

Comment: Or else you may have overwritten a function by creating a variable with the same name. Maybe `zeros`...?

Comment: You should check your question frequently in the initial 20 minutes (at least) to see if somebody has a question. We invest time to answer your questions.

Comment: the error in line  
old_size= size(image1);
then it says error in a row and col that doesnt exist im my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because you declare `size` as a variable with the line:

```
%    kernel size
size = 8 ;
```

By doing this you are overwriting the MATLAB function `size`, which you then try to call with:

```
old_size= size(image1);
```

Can you see what the problem is when doing that? Don't use `size` as a variable name and it should work OK, provided that `old_size(1)` and `old_size(2)` are even numbers (because you are dividing them by `red_factor` which is 2).

So to summarise, use something like:

```
%    kernel size
kernel_size = 8 ;
```

and replace all subsequent occurences of `size` by `kernel_size`, except when you are actually calling the function `size` in `old_size= size(image1);`.

Comment: @abdallahkamal Glad it helped. If it solved your problem, please accept the answer to help other people in case they have a similar problem.